# recyclerview not scrolling smoothly in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Hi in the below code If I am using recyclerview in the same way using swipe.if I am swipe recycler item that time showing edit/share.

using below code My recyclerview not scrolling smoothly .

```
 proposalAdapter = new ProposalAdapter(requireContext(), listSalesStageOpportunity);
        recyclerViewOpportunity.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
        recyclerViewOpportunity.setAdapter(proposalAdapter);
        recyclerViewOpportunity.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

Adapter.java:

```
holder.cardView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {


                v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);

                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Why do you have a `OnTouchListener` of Item View of List ? This is causing problem ..

Comment: @ADM can you please which is better approach

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can add following code to your recycler view  XML file `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"` where you have declared.

Comment: android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" in java file